# How to redirect all URLs to a new domain

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm shutting down an old site and want to redirect all URLs to the homepage of a new domain. Is there a module or quick php snippet that can do just that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with trying to do it with PHP or a module is that PHP doesn't handle every request; for example, if someone deep linked to a file, no PHP solution would help.

So the easiest (and most complete) way to do this is actually with Apache (or whatever web server you happen to be using):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You can do this in the host configuration file or the `.htaccess` file: assuming the old site is a Drupal site, you'll want to place everything except the first line immediately after `RewriteEngine On` (around line 58 in Drupal 7.x).