# Redirect to a new domain?

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm currently running my drupal site on a subdomain (a.example.com). I would like to temporarily redirect any requests to example.com and www. example.com to a.example.com.

Mark Trapp already offered a [great solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18347/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain) using .htaccess files. In this case I would prefer to add a little module code. I was thing about checking $GLOBALS['base_url'] and then redirecting with drupal_goto(). Are those the right functions and which hook would I use?

Comment: Why not htaccess? This is in my opinion much easier.

Comment: since this is a temporary fix I'm more comfortable using a module or module code. If I modify the .htaccess then I can't test on my local machine and I can't even test on my dev and test site. And I don't like to make changes directly on the live site without having them tested first ;-)

Comment: If this is temporary, you should really use a 302 and not a 301.  As 302 is a temporary redirect, it should prevent spiders from thinking that a.example.com is the new canonical URL for your site.

Comment: I'm hosting on my computer for developing about 6 sites. So it is technically possible to test that too. I'm using for that virtual hosts and edited my hosts file. e.g. `127.0.2.1 a.example.com` `127.0.2.2 b.example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the [Domain 301 Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows sites to 301 redirect to a domain that is marked as the main domain. This means you can have all subdomains and other domains pointing to the site 301 redirect to a domain that you choose as the main domain. This provides great SEO benefit.

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I need, I can't write code as quickly as installing and configuring that module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to do this is by using the [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) function in your `page.tpl` file.
It's bad practice because this file is almost the last one to be called, but it will do the trick.